# ReactNative Webview

Tags: reactjs, webview, native, production

React js : I am trying to open my react js production build folder under which the one html file is placed after run npm run build.

React Native: I am using react-native-webview Plugin for open the same index.html file. For android I placed this folder under assets.

The codebase giving me error File_Not_Found.

The build html file is minify html file. When I try to use any url here or any development plain html it is working fine. For this minify file it is not working.

Please help.

I am using this code for android react native.

if(isAndroid){
      console.log(isAndroid);
      return (
          
      )
    }

I want to open production this react js build folder html file in react native webview.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object

```
const index = require('./assets/index.html');
```

set your source to the object instead of using a uri.